# Kubernetes bare-metal setup for https connection

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Hello everybody my kubernetes bare metal setup is as follows from this tutorial:
https://mickael.kerjean.me/2020/06/04/installing-kubernetes-the-easy-way/

Besides one thing that I only use one master node and tainted it to a worker node, so I have a single-machine Kubernetes cluster.

Now with the following Deployment, Service, ClusterIssuer and Ingress I´m trying to not only get a http but also a https connection via NodePort. But sadly I just can reach both addresses via http through `playground.mywebsite.com:30081` and `playground.mywebsite.com:31000` (obviously I changed my original website).

What am I doing wrong to get a https connection?
Thanks for your help and hit me up if you´re missing any information of some logs or resources that need to be described for you.
This is my following Code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-deployment
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: bhargavshah86/kube-test:v0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "250m"
          requests:
            memory: 128Mi
            cpu: "80m"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000  
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30081
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: ssl-hello-world
spec:
  acme:
    email: my@email.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: ssl-hello-world
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress: 
          class: nginx
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "ssl-hello-world"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - playground.mywebsite.com
    secretName: hello-world
  rules:
  - host: playground.mywebsite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 443
```

This is my result of `kubectl describe certificates`:

```
Name:         hello-world
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  acme.cert-manager.io/http01-override-ingress-name: hello-world
              cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate: true
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-10-20T09:57:46Z
  Generation:          2
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:acme.cert-manager.io/http01-override-ingress-name:
          f:cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate:
        f:ownerReferences:
          .:
          k:{"uid":"ad7f81f5-39da-4ed7-855c-19262f012094"}:
            .:
            f:apiVersion:
            f:blockOwnerDeletion:
            f:controller:
            f:kind:
            f:name:
            f:uid:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:dnsNames:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:group:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:secretName:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
        f:nextPrivateKeySecretName:
        f:notAfter:
        f:notBefore:
        f:renewalTime:
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2020-10-20T11:49:41Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  hello-world
    UID:                   ad7f81f5-39da-4ed7-855c-19262f012094
  Resource Version:        3376660
  Self Link:               /apis/cert-manager.io/v1/namespaces/default/certificates/hello-world
  UID:                     f40ce72b-40b8-4b2d-a7e3-b5f637788e01
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    playground.mywebsite.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       Issuer
    Name:       ssl-hello-world
  Secret Name:  hello-world
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2020-10-20T11:49:41Z
    Message:                     Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Reason:                      Ready
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Ready
    Last Transition Time:        2020-10-20T11:47:05Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret was previously issued by Issuer.cert-manager.io/ssl-letsencrypt-hello-world
    Reason:                      IncorrectIssuer
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  hello-world-vpbxz
  Not After:                     2021-01-18T11:49:41Z
  Not Before:                    2020-10-20T11:49:41Z
  Renewal Time:                  2020-12-19T11:49:41Z
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                From          Message
  ----    ------     ----               ----          -------
  Normal  Issuing    50m                cert-manager  Issuing certificate as Secret was previously issued by Issuer.cert-manager.io/ssl-letsencrypt-hello-world
  Normal  Requested  50m                cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "hello-world-rl8m5"
  Normal  Issuing    48m                cert-manager  Issued temporary certificate
  Normal  Reused     48m (x2 over 50m)  cert-manager  Reusing private key stored in existing Secret resource "hello-world"
```

Comment: How are you trying to connect, command? Did you configure your firewall?

Comment: I´m trying to connect via playground.mywebsite.com:30081 and playground.mywebsite.com:31000
I hit the command "sudo ufw disable". Should I enable later on?